import module from github in nodejs give me error
I write a simple app in nodeJS and I imported a module, but I have this error:
TypeError [ERR_IMPORT_ASSERTION_TYPE_MISSING]: Module "file:/// *** /node_modules/ *** /package.json" needs an import assertion of type "json"
package.json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./src/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "<my-module>": "git+https://<my-user>:<my-token>@github.com/<user>/<module>.git"
  }
}


Nodejs is complaining that you are missing assert {type: 'json'} when importing package.json file of the module you are trying to use.
Module needs an import assertion of type "json"
I think the solution is you have to write assert {type: 'json'} at last of the import.
For eg:
import moduleData from './node_modules/<your-module>/package.json' assert { type: 'json' };

If the error is still there, the module might be outdated, you should update it or if there is no update and you cannot update it, convert your project back to commonJS.
You can switch back to avoid the error:
package.json
"type": "commonjs",

If it's still not helping, I think your best bet is to downgrade node.
Hope this helps you.
